# Apple watch app does not appear on Apps Available on Watch iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-watch

I have developed an Apple Watch app for an old iOS app. If I install it directly through Xcode it works fine but when I want to install it through the Watch app from my iPhone, it does not appear on the "apps available" list.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have unchecked `Copy only when installing` under the main iOS app target's Build Phases.

[image]